# How can they say my question _cannot be reasonably answered_?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, closed-questions, not-a-real-question

I've put [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755277/which-is-the-better-way-to-deal-with-thumbnails) on SO and the question was closed as `not a real question`. So I read the FAQ, it says -

> **not a real question**
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.
>   This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or
>   rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For
>   help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

How can they say it *cannot be reasonably answered* when the question already has 5 answers?

If it couldn't be answered, then how come it has 5 answers.

**Question** - Why do some questions which do get answers are closed as unreal?

PS: same problem here - [How does Facebook do it? Directories or 404 custom error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537856/how-does-facebook-do-it-directories-or-404-custom-error)

Comment: It is reopened.

Comment: closing question requires at least 5 votes, each one must vote and do some clicks, I think instead of this, they can improve the question if possible to make the question improved!

Comment: @Akam: What does that mean?

Comment: is there any ambiguous words?

Comment: I read that as "Instead of closing the question, how about editing it to improve it?"  Did I get it right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think he means moderators should improve the questions rather than closing them.

Comment: yes very right ;)

Comment: @Akam: Well, your comment illustrates why that doesn't always work... We can't fix questions we don't understand.

Comment: @sandy - moderators may have other things to do. Closing gives the OP a sign that they should fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have changed the title of your post to reflect the actual question being asked, and reopened it.

Negative on the Facebook question.  Questions to the effect of "I like this feature on that website, can you reverse-engineer it for me and tell me how it works" are off-topic.  What possessed you to ask that question *twice?*

After reviewing your questions, I suggest that you avoid:

1. Questions that can be readily solved by reading the manual or gaining some basic knowledge of the subject matter,
2. Questions that invite speculation or discussion,
3. Questions asking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend a lot on your environment, on the workload (many new images created, rarely asked for, light load ~~-> create on the fly; images rarely changed, often requested ~~-> precompute; have spare CPU cycles elsewhere, plenty of space here ~~-> precompute there; ...). As it stands, you could very well get *lots* of wild guesses, but no answers. And if yo narrow it down, the detailed answer is unlikely to be of help to anybody else.

Comment: Well, thumbnails are really small, compared to the original image. Generating them every time an image is requested seems redundant, and wasteful of processor resources.  As the posted answer points out, storage is a lot cheaper than processor time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that depends on how frequently they are used for a particular image. If infrequently enough, you can win by creating on the fly (and possibly caching).